# VSTO - Open form in reading pane

Tags: c#, forms, outlook, vsto

What I've done so far:

```
<contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuAttachments">
  <button id="MyActionId"
          insertBeforeMso="PreviewAttach"
          imageMso="BlogPublish"
          label="Upload to ..."
          visible="true"
          onAction="UploadTo_OnAction"/>
</contextMenu>
```

Code behind the button:

```
            var count = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Inspectors.Count;
            if (count > 0)
            {
                var i = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Inspectors[1];

            try { i.SetCurrentFormPage("MyAddin.UploadToFormRegion"); } catch (Exception) { }
```

The region form:

```
[Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.FormRegionMessageClass (Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.FormRegionMessageClassAttribute.Note)]

[Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.FormRegionName("MyAddin.UploadToFormRegion")]
```

Works perfeclty when I open the mail and then right click because an Inspector is active.
What about when I'm in the reading pane view ? Here when I right-click on the attachment, I've no inspector and I can't open my form.

Any workaround?